# Fail to add/replace basicHttpBinding with wsDualHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

**I'm new in the WCF**

I wrote some server that work on IIS 7.5 
I using the basicHttpBinding endpoint - and i want replace or add support for the wsDualHttpBinding endpoint.

So i used the WCF configuration tool to change the basicHttpBinding to wsDualHttpBinding. 
And nothing work.

I change back to http and add new endpoint that will define as wsDualHttpBinding - and nothing work.

( i change in the client also )

How can i support the wsDualHttpBinding ?
Why this is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change the endpoint on the server, you will have to change it on the client as well.

If you change to wsDualHttpBindingon the server, and do nothing to the client, it will remain as basicHttpBinding, and it will not work. The binding on the client will have to be compliant with the server binding for the communication to work between client and server.

If you have already tried this, please let us know which error message you get when trying to run your program.

Comment: But i said in my massage that i changed the client also - and this is not helping :)

Comment: But what error are you getting? Simply knowing that it does not work is not helping :)

Comment: The client can't access to the server - the exception is about security.

Comment: Any reason you can't post it as a update to your original post? I guess the error is related to security also then ;)